# Is it possible to access the WebView cache?

Tags: android, caching, webview, android-webview, browser-cache

I have a WebView in which I can access to web pages. Is it possible, when I am offline to have access for example to the images that have been previously downloaded?
And if it is possible how can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By download you mean viewed? if you downloaded to the phone/tablet you should be able to go to your gallery and see them

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, at least for Android 2.3 and lower.

If you want to see the entire cache folder, it is situated here:

```
<android cache dir>/<your app package>/cache/webviewCache/
```

If you already know the URL of the cached image, you can get the actual file so:

```
String uri = "http://the url of the image that you need";
String hashCode = String.format("%08x", uri.hashCode());
File file = new File(new File(getCacheDir(), "webviewCache"), hashCode);
// if the call file.exist() returns true, then the file presents in the cache
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone else faces this problem, I had a similar issue and I solve it managing(saving and retrieving) my app cache manually. [Here it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17388989/check-if-file-already-exists-in-webview-cache-android/17510721#17510721) my related post.

Comment: Same here, implemented my own cache for the app webview and I intercept everything with `shouldinterceptrequest`

Comment: @AnnArbor87, can u show us what you do in shouldinterceptrequest method?

Answer (score -1):

`CacheManager`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CacheManager.html

Comment: Just an FYI, CacheManager was deprecated as of ICS and was removed in 4.2. http://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/17/changes/pkg_android.webkit.html (And the above link yields a 404).