# Check if file already exists in webview cache android

Tags: android, caching, webview, android-webview

In my app I have an activity with a webview wich loads different images. Before loading the webview, I need to know if the image is already cached in the webview cache. I've found this working solution for 2.3 android devices and lower:

```
String uri = "http://the url of the image that you need";
String hashCode = String.format("%08x", uri.hashCode());
File file = new File(new File(getCacheDir(), "webviewCache"), hashCode);
// if the call file.exist() returns true, then the file presents in the cache
```

from the post "[Is it possible to access the WebView cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7809483/is-it-possible-to-access-the-webview-cache?rq=1)" but I would like to find the solution for all devices, so any help will be appreciated... May webview cache directory have changed?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found a workaround. I save what I need manually in my app cache directory, and when I have to load it again I check if it is inside that directory. That solution works on all android versions.